# Which version of drupal, php, mysql combination will work on RHEL6? Which version of drupal, php, RHEL will work if we need to use mysql 8.0?

Tags: 7

We have a working application which runs on RHEL6 with Drupal 7, php 5.3.3 and mySql 5.1.73.
We are planning to migrate it AWS with latest versions which gets support. We need to know the working combination of below modules
Drupal version
PHP version
RHEL version
MYSQL version

Comment: As side note, Drupal 9 requires MySQL 5.7.8+. I am not sure Drupal 9 or Drupal 8 has been tested with MySQL 8.

Comment: Does Drupal 7 work with mysql 8.0. If yes, what is the compatible php version? Should we use Rhel6 or Rhel 7 for this?

Answer (score 3):

Drupal doesn't have an opinion on which flavour or version of Linux you use, just that the [system requirements](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements) are met. So it looks like your actual question around Drupal is the one you've put in the comments:

> Does Drupal 7 work with mysql 8.0

The answer to that is no, MySQL 8 is not currently supported by Drupal 7.

There are ongoing efforts to make that happen, though, you can follow [Mysql 8 support on Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2978575) for the details.